# Can't access resources file

Tags: ios, objective-c, embedded-resource

I'm developing an iOS application and I want to load two CSV files into my app.

As you can see in the following image, those files are in *Resources* group:

[image]

I use this to get its file path:

`filePath =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Familias" ofType:@"txt"];`

And this is the code for `Util readTitleFromCSV:`

```
+(void)readTitleFromCSV:(NSString*)path Entity:(NSString*)entityName
{
    AppDelegate* appDelegate =
        (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSString *fileDataString =
        [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     error:nil];

    NSArray *linesArray = [fileDataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    [ ... ]

}
```

But `fileDataString` is nil and I don't get any error.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: When you added the resources, did you make sure to check the box to add it to the target App? Sometimes I forget or it doesn't get checked. You might have to remove the reference and then add it again.

Comment: First validate that the `.csv` files are being copied into the app bundle (using Finder).  If not then it's probably that you need to add them to the *Copy Files* build script.

Comment: @trojanfoe Where is that *Copy Files* build script?

Comment: Isn't that a standard build script in the Project's *Build Phases* tab?  I know that when I add a header to my static library project I need to add it to the script else the header file won't be copied to the output directory correctly. I would assume something similar exists for iOS app resources...

Comment: @VansFannel Go to your target, switch to build phases, then down to "Copy Bundle Resources". Expand that and make sure your files are included there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an `NSError` into your file and check why the call is failing. Likely, there is some encoding issue.

Before that, check that the file is included in your app bundle by going to your target build phases pane (see image below for guidance)

[image]

Comment: I get this error : The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)

Comment: Yes, both files are in that panel.

Comment: error 261 this seems to be caused by CRLF at the end of lines (windows style)... replace them to LF (unix style) in a text editor.

Comment: textedit is good, I think; just save the file under a different name, then replace the original. or you could use vi from the terminal...